# Что значит "бить баклуши"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Кто такие "баклуши" и зачем их бить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Баклуши - деревянные заготовки для ложек. Работа с ними считалась не самым тяжёлым занятием, поэтому бить баклуши - бездельничать.